# Questions regarding Google API

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Can somebody please answer the question below regarding the Google API for Charts?

1- Is Google Charts API completely independent of any other JS libraries or software like Flash etc?

2- Does it work completely offline (using the new version)?

3- Is it completely free for commercial usage?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The google charts api uses js libraries.
2. You can't use it offline

> your computer must have live access to http://www.google.com/jsapi in order to use charts. This is because the visualization libraries that your page requires are loaded dynamically before you use them. The code for loading the appropriate library is part of the included jsapi script, and is called when you invoke the google.load() method. Our terms of service do not allow you to download the google.load or google.visualization code to use offline.

(https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#offline)

3 . The api is completly free (https://developers.google.com/chart/terms?hl=nl#license)

Comment: @asgallant where can i find your post, i don't see it or an url?

Comment: My post should be up now.

Comment: i'm sorry your right i missed this: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#offline

Answer (score 1):

1. The API is dependent on Google's internal libraries (nothing you have to specifically load), but generally not any external libraries.  The exceptions are for the AnnotatedTimeLine and Motion charts, which are Flash-based.  3rd-party visualizations may be dependent on other libraries.
2. You cannot use the API offline.  Downloading the API and hosting it locally is strictly forbidden in the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/chart/terms).
3. The API is free for almost all commercial usage, see Terms of Service for details.